# Executing celery task through a listener on a RabbitMQ queue

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery, pika

I am trying to run a script for a messaging consumer that listens to a rabbitMQ instance and executes a celery job based on that message value. I am receiving issues with circular dependencies and cannot figure what exactly is the issue and how to fix it. Below are my file examples:

celery.py
import os
from celery import Celery

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "projectTest.settings")

app = Celery(
    "appTest",
    broker=os.environ.get("RABBITMQ_CONN_STRING"),
    backend="rpc://",
)

# Optional configuration, see the application user guide.
app.conf.update(
    result_expires=3600,
)

app.config_from_object("appTest.celeryConfig", namespace="CELERY")

app.autodiscover_tasks()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.start()
```

class_task.py
from celery import app

```
logger = get_task_logger("emailSvcCelery")

class ClassTask(app.Task):
    name = "class-task"

    def run(self):
        print('Task Ran!')


app.register_task(ClassTask)
```

message_consumer.py

```
import os
import json
import pika
from tasks.class_task import ClassTask

connection_parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters(os.environ.get("RABBITMQ_CONN_STRING"))
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(connection_parameters)
channel = connection.channel()

queues = (
  'queue-test'
)
for q in queues:
  channel.queue_declare(queue=q, durable=True)

def callback(channel, method, properties, body):
  ClassTask().delay()

channel.basic_consume(queue='queue-test', on_message_callback=callback, auto_ack=True)
print("Started Consuming...")
channel.start_consuming()
```

The error I am recieving is below after running `python3 message_consumer.py`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/message_consumer.py", line 4, in <module>
    from tasks.class_task import ClassTask
  File "/class_task.py", line 1, in <module>
    from celery import app
  File "/celery.py", line 2, in <module>
    from celery import Celery
ImportError: cannot import name 'Celery' from partially initialized module 'celery' (most likely due to a circular import) (/celery.py)
```

I am somewhat new to python and need some help, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Update -**

I see now, the issue is a bit deeper. You need to use whats called a static reference for your parent class when creating your child class 'ClassTask'. Its a bit hard to see the import errors since some of it is hanging off at the top and normally it might make sense and seem like a non important part of the code.

celery.py

```
from celery import Celery
```

class_task.py

```
from celery import app
```

Notice here that in celery.py you are importing the celery library to create the app object. In class_task.py you are trying to import that object like you normally might from a local python file, but instead you are looking in the celery library for 'app'.

The best way to do this is to use the actual parent class that the celery library uses when creating `Celery` object. From the [documentation](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/application.html), read 'Evolving the API':

```
from celery import Task
from celery.registry import tasks

class Hello(Task):
    queue = 'hipri'

    def run(self, to):
        return 'hello {0}'.format(to)
tasks.register(Hello)
```

Your application tries to register the task in a similar fashion also, but instead of calling `register` or `register_task`, it should use a task decorator.

From 'Evolving the API', "it was decided that passing arbitrary call-able’s was an anti-pattern, since it makes it very hard to use serializers other than pickle, and the feature was removed in 2.0, replaced by task decorators":

```
from celery import app

@app.task(queue='hipri')
class ClassTask(Task):
    name = "class-task"

    def run(self):
        print('Task Ran!')
```

Where you are importing app only to set the task.

This would be in your code:

```
from celery import Task
from celery import app
# Set the task to expire after 45 seconds if it cannot finish
@app.task(expires=45)
class ClassTask(Task):
    name = "class-task"

    def run(self):
        print('Task Ran!')
```

I dont recommend setting it up like this, but instead, setting up a `shared_task`, and then using the Django administration to modify the database and add the task in on a preferred periodic schedule which the celery library sets up for you.

In your case, this would look something like this class_task.py, but you could delete that file altogether and put it in celery.py after you create the app object.

```
from celery import Task
from celery import shared_task

@shared_task(expires=45)
class ClassTask(Task):
    name = "class-task"

    def run(self):
        print('Task Ran!')
```

See 'Introducing the Django Admin' from the Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/intro/tutorial02/) to setup your administration. Then, login and add your task where the Model for periodic tasks shows and add in your desired period of time to rerun the task or select 'one-time task'. When putting in the celery task name, refer to it as follows:

```
DjangoMainAppName.class_task.ClassTask
```

**One potential issue -**

This is a package dependency error unfortunately. Celery is unable to initialize because it uses a method from a package which has been depreciated. Celery uses an interface from `importlib-metadata` which was deprecated in version 5. Rollback the version using this command:

```
pip install importlib-metadata==4.8.3
```

Comment: Hmm, interesting, i added the package and version to my requirements.txt and am still running into the same issue. This is the version I have when running `pip list`: `importlib-metadata      4.8.3`

Comment: Oh I see, the issue must be deeper, I updated my answer.